# how to post data in x-www-form-urlencoded format using dart?

Tags: flutter, api, dart, post, x-www-form-urlencoded

I need to post this data in x-www-form-urlencoded format

```
Map<String, dynamic> body = {
      'data': [
        {
          'prefix': '225',
          'phone': '1234567890',
          'email': 'test@gmail.com',
          'name': 'test',
          'surname': 'test',
        },
      ],
    };
```

I tried the following approach to convert my data but it returns a syntax error.

```
String bodyString = body.entries.map((entry) =>
    '${Uri.encodeQueryComponent(entry.key)}=${Uri.encodeQueryComponent(entry.value.toString())}'
).join('&');
```

but when I use postman like on the picture then everything is fine[potman screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KhPt.png)

post data in x-www-form-urlencoded format

Comment: Your postman screenshot does indeed show a form encoded body, but interestingly the actual field appears to be a valid piece of JSON. There's no need to do the `bodies.entries` code you show (where did you find that?) - as the http package will do that for you. In your `http.post` set `body` to `{'data': json.encode([{'prefix':'225',}])}`

Comment: I just tried your approach and it still doesn't help me.
could you be more explicit? i am also a beginner with flutter/dart

Comment: Update your question showing the new code you tried.